# Como mostrar uma descrição do método no auto-complete do Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Estou desenvolvendo um Framework e gostaria que quando o usuário digita-se e o auto-complete sugerisse o método, abaixo/acima aparecesse para que ele serve. Tipo isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Achei que era só comentar assim:

```
/**
 * <Descrição aqui>
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

A partir do xcode 8.2 isso é possível automaticamente, experimente colocar o cursor em cima da função que você quer documentar e em seguinte apertar a seguinte combinação de botão:

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Assim ele vai apresentar algo parecido com isso:

```
/// <#Description#>
///
/// - parameter bar: <#bar description#>
///
/// - returns: <#return value description#>
```

Comment: cmd + option + / na verdade abre o popup de emojis @Lucas :P

Comment: @FelipeRicieri o que abre os emojis é o cmd + ctrl + space

Comment: Verifique a versão que você esta usando do xcode. O que pode ser e que seus atalhos do teclado estão trocados. A supetão do atalho que mencionei é apenas para auto completar com base no método. 

Caso o autocomplete não esta funcionando, tente então apenas colocar essa descrição como coloquei acima que irá pegar a documentação do método @FelipeRicieri

Comment: eu que estava usando o atalho errado, o comando que passou realmente funciona. Mas ele não me deu o comportamento que eu queria, ilustrado na figura acima.